# Cimbalino appbar, pivot with UserControls

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, cimbalino

Ok, another question about Cimbalino appbar.

I have a pivot with several pages as UserControls. What i want is to have different appbars for every UC (page). But i can't define appbar inside UC, because that throws exception 
*"This ApplicationBarBehavior element can only be attached to the LayoutRoot element"*, but root is Pivot itself.

PS: definitely i'd like to use mvvm way, and keep appbar in UC's viewmodels, not switching through SelectedIndex in Pivot's codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, looking like MultiApplicationBarBehavior is to the resque.
http://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/03/11/cimbalino-windows-phone-toolkit-multiapplicationbarbehavior/

Though, i'm not sure that it is 100% usefull: it is binded to index, but what if i'd like to switch some pages?

Comment: If you need I have a sample on how to use it the MVVM'ed way!

Comment: Sure, i'd like to check that. I really dont like this binding to pivot index.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you mentioning the Pivot Index... because my solution is currently based on it also! :\

Comment: Yeah, appbar is working nice, in general :)
Except that thing, that its hard-binded to index.

It is solved in sh appbar (in case you're interested): http://shwp.codeplex.com/

Comment: @PedroLamas Hi, any news about pivot index binding?